# how do i make foreach echo a ftp with auto-login?

Tags: php, ftp, foreach

i have a script that allows me to port my in-game chat from Call Of Duty 4 to a small window using php script live from my gaming server so my members and visitors can see in-game chat live from my site.

Only problem is my server is locked by ftp (tcadmin so no way of direct url for file) so i want a way to read the mp_games.log file in the directory

i think only way is to connect through ftp i guess but it'll need to auto-login

the script is: ( this is only a part of the script where im having the problem )

```
    <?php
  $maxMessages = 40;
  $messageArr  = array();

  foreach(file('file:///home/serverexample/main/games_mp.log') AS $value) {
    if(strstr($value,'say;')) {
      $messageArr[]=$value;
    }
  }
```

what i need help with is to make the foreach go to the ftp in my site into a specific path where it can read the game_mp.log ..

i was thinking something similar to:  ftp://user:pass@ftp.domain.com/serverexample/main/games_mp.log

Can you tell me how to modify the script in order to possibly download it onto a dir in local address but it'll need to be constantly downloading which im afraid might cause lag.

The other way i was thinking of, if possible is to read directly the game_mp.log file

games_mp.log is readable as txt .. and is always being updated by server .. any way to make the foreach(file replaced by ftp so it takes directly the info from the ftp server ?

preferably being able to male the script read the file without having to download it ..

and if there is no other way but downloading it can you guide me through that as well ?

Many thanks hope i made myself clear of what i need

Comment: Can you not fread the file? http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php - or are you saying the file is remote and inaccessible otherwise?

Comment: I don't think you can read the file continuously, if that's what you're looking for. The FTP protocol doesn't include this capability.

Comment: @Kai Qing, the file is remote and can only be accessed using ftp and ofc user and pass to auth

Comment: @Barmar if not possible to read continuoysly then maybe add a refresh interval of 1 minute ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `login` and `download` the file with the FTP functions of PHP, look at the list of manuals  http://www.php.net/ftp

An alternative (not recommend) is WGET: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/wget-command-with-username-password/

Comment: i know the list of manuals, but something im doing is wrong, i cant get it to work. can you plz provide me sample script would be highly appreciated